# Friend doesn't has Python module installed is there a "workaround"?

Tags: python, module

I send mir friend a Python script with the module pytube.
But he hasn't installed the package so he couldn't run the script. It was not the big of a deal because easily installed pytube. But how can I prevent this? So if the script/program had more than one module but my friend doesn't want to install them all how can i "compile" the program that he doesn't need to install the modules?
I heard about Docker is this the right way or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package your code or use docker indeed. Although, this costs more time then you want to spend on it probably.

Comment: Does my friend has to install Docker?

Comment: @SchnellfeuerXD yes